# C : Unidentified if evaluation issue

Tags: c, if-statement

This is kinda more complicated than that, but for short, I am trying to create a consensus sequences for families of sequences (strings made only out of A, C, G and T characters), and I can't identify where the function I made fails. Here it is :

```
SEQUENCE calculate_cons(FAMILY FAM)
{
    SEQUENCE cons;
    int maxlenght=seq_with_max_char(FAM);

    for(int i=0; i<maxlenght; i++)
    {
        int nA=0;
        int nC=0;
        int nG=0;
        int nT=0;

        for(int j=0; j<FAM.size; j++)
        {
            if(FAM.seq[j].c[i]=='A')
            {
                nA++;
            }
            if(FAM.seq[j].c[i]=='C')
            {
                nC++;
            }
            if(FAM.seq[j].c[i]=='G')
            {
                nG++;
            }
            if(FAM.seq[j].c[i]=='T')
            {
                nT++;
            }
        }

        if((nA==nC) || (nA==nG) || (nA==nT))
        {
            cons.c[i]='.';
        }
        else
        {
            if((nA>nC) && (nA>nG) && (nA>nT))
            {
                cons.c[i]='A';
            }
            if((nC>nA) && (nC>nG) && (nC>nT))
            {
                cons.c[i]='C';
            }
            if((nG>nA) && (nG>nC) && (nG>nT))
            {
                cons.c[i]='G';
            }
            if((nT>nA) && (nT>nC) && (nT>nG))
            {
                cons.c[i]='T';
            }
        }
    }

    cons.lenght=maxlenght;
    cons.ispartfam=true;

    return cons;
}
```

**The issue :** With this code, consensus sequences are only be made out of 'A' and '.'.
As an exemple, if a family contains :

TCCTATGGAATCTTTTTA

TTCTATGGAATCTTTTTA

The consensus sequence will be :

....A...AA.......A

The function writes '.' when there is not 2 times A, and it writes 'A' otherwise.
The line where it fails is probably if((nA==nC) || (nA==nG) || (nA==nT)) since if I compare with nC, the consensus family will only contain 'C' and '.'.

EDIT : You'll find a minimal reproductive exemple below. I couldn't be more minimal than that while remaining clear.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int nbseq=2;
    int seqsize=5;
    char tseq[nbseq][seqsize];
    char cons[seqsize];

    tseq[0][0]='A';
    tseq[0][1]='C';
    tseq[0][2]='A';
    tseq[0][3]='T';
    tseq[0][4]='A';
    tseq[1][0]='G';
    tseq[1][1]='A';
    tseq[1][2]='A';
    tseq[1][3]='A';
    tseq[1][4]='G';

    for(int i=0; i<seqsize; i++)
    {
        int nA=0;
        int nC=0;
        int nG=0;
        int nT=0;

        for(int j=0; j<nbseq; j++)
        {
            if(tseq[j][i]=='A')
            {
                nA++;
            }
            if(tseq[j][i]=='C')
            {
                nC++;
            }
            if(tseq[j][i]=='G')
            {
                nG++;
            }
            if(tseq[j][i]=='T')
            {
                nT++;
            }
        }

        if((nA==nC) || (nA==nG) || (nA==nT))
        {
            cons[i]='.';
        }
        else
        {
            if((nA>nC) && (nA>nG) && (nA>nT))
            {
                cons[i]='A';
            }
            if((nC>nA) && (nC>nG) && (nC>nT))
            {
                cons[i]='C';
            }
            if((nG>nA) && (nG>nC) && (nG>nT))
            {
                cons[i]='G';
            }
            if((nT>nA) && (nT>nC) && (nT>nG))
            {
                cons[i]='T';
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<nbseq; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<seqsize; j++)
        {
        printf("%c", tseq[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    for(int i=0; i<seqsize; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", cons[i]);
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please post the definition of `SEQUENCE` and `FAMILY`? What is the input of the function? What should be the output of the function? `The function writes '.'` - I do not see the function outputting anything, only returning. Please post a compilable [MCVE], something that is easy for others to work with, that way you will get help much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that the problematic line is

> ```
>        if((nA==nC) || (nA==nG) || (nA==nT))
> ```

I think the idea behind this logic is supposed to be that you need a unique maximum base count at a given position to inform a consensus, so ties must be rejected.  Unfortunately, the idea is both flawed *and* incorrectly implemented.

It is flawed because ties don't matter *in general*, but rather only when there is a tie for *maximum* count at a given position.  Note in particular that if every base at a given position is A then none of those conditions hold, but if every base is any of the others then two of them will both evaluate to true, in the form of `0 == 0`.

It is incorrectly implemented because you do not test all the pairs.  There are six distinct ways to form pairs from a set of four distinct elements, but you have provided only three.  The missing ones would be `nC==nG`, `nC==nT`, and `nG==nT`.  If you had included those as well then your output would consist only of '.'s, but you happened to omit exactly the ones that would permit consensus A to pass through.

What's worse, this particular bit is *pointless*.  You don't need to pre-check for ties, because the part that tries to identify a unique maximum will exclude ties (for the maximum) anyway.  Instead of pre-checking for ties, then, a more effective approach would simply set '.' as a fallback when none of the real consensus conditions is satisfied.  There are multiple ways to do that, for instance:

```
            # Skip the explicit tie-checking altogether, and just do this ...
            if ((nA > nC) && (nA > nG) && (nA > nT)) {
                cons.c[i] = 'A';
            } else if ((nC > nA) && (nC > nG) && (nC > nT)) {
                cons.c[i] = 'C';
            } else if ((nG > nA) && (nG > nC) && (nG > nT)) {
                cons.c[i] = 'G';
            } else if ((nT > nA) && (nT > nC) && (nT > nG)) {
                cons.c[i] = 'T';
            } else {
                cons.c[i] = '.';
            }
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, that is a great exemple "else if" are important btw. I'll include a mre in the op to reproduce the error since I made it anyways.